# Deserialize of boolean data types in json file not working in python

Tags: python, json

I have a json file, below is the content is not decoding string ("false") to False in python 2.7.6 (not tested in python3)

```
{
  "qps": 30,
  "force_push": "false"
}
```

Below is the code, which is not decoding boolean values

```
import json
res=json.load(open('demo.json'))
```

res object should be like `{ "qps": 30, "force_push": False}`

Comment: Anything in quotes is a string.  Boolean is `false`, without the quotes.

Comment: the issue is the serialization of that json ... its being properly decoded

Comment: Can you please add the output which you get on executing that script?

Comment: "the content is not decoding boolean string " There is no such thing as a boolean string in JSON. There are booleans, and there are strings. You have a string. That's why it's being decoded into a python `str`.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to remove the quotes in your json file and then use `json.dumps`.

```
{
  "qps": 30,
  "force_push": false
}
```

In python:

```
import json
res=json.load(open('demo.json'))
output = json.dumps(res) # '{"qps": 30, "force_push": false}'
```

If you want `false` to be a string in the resulting json you will need to explicitly convert the values in the dictionary that is loaded from `False` to `"false"` before doing `json.dumps`.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by having proper json values

```
{
  "qps": 30,
  "force_push": false
}
```

Instead of "false" in string notation, I specified false. Now deserialization working.